# How to implement Reference counting in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, concurrency, garbage-collection

read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting).

I need to implement a variation of such an interface, say we are given a large memory space to manage there should be getmem(size) and free(pointer to block) functions that has to make sure free(pointer to block) can actually free the memory if and only if all processes using that block are done using it.

What I was thinking about doing is to define a `Collectable` struct as pointer to block, size of it, and process using it count. then whenever a process using a `Collectable` struct instance for the first time it has to explicitly increment the count, and whenever the process `free()`'s it, the count is decremented.

The problem with this approach is that all processes must respond to that interface and make it explicitly work : whenever assigning collectable pointer to an instance the process must explicitly inc that counter, which does not satisfy me, I was thinking maybe there is a way to create a macro for this to happen implicitly in every assignment?

I'm seeking of ways to approach this problem for a while, so other approaches and ideas would be great...

**EDIT :** the above approach doesn't satisfy me not only because it doesn't look nice but  mostly because I cant assume a running process's code would care for updating my count. I need a way to make sure its done without changing the process's code...

Comment: This is not a problem for C. This is exactly why other languages were created based on C, for example: Objective-C, C++, C#, etc.

Comment: I know, but that is what i got to do for homework... so...

Comment: The fact that every pointer copy must be instrumented is not a "problem with this approach": it's the fundamental problem of reference counting.

Comment: I'm not even sure you can implement reference counting within C. In C++ you have constructors and destructors which allow code to "automatically" without extra effort from the programmer.

Comment: Other languages are irrelvant, I am very familiar with Java and its GC, so i know there are better languages to work with in this case, but then again my HW is to implement this idea in C. so stop giving me the use diffrent lanagauge argument.

Comment: Some might say that Objective C naming conventions plus manual retain/release calls are an example of implementing reference counting in C (or something very close).

Comment: @MikeBantegui: You absolutely can, it just takes more effort from the programmer.

Comment: @OfekRon: Mike's point is that you cannot do this robustly in C, as there are no options to overload assignment operators, etc. unlike in C++.  It relies on the programmer calling a special function (or using a special macro) every time he/she wants to copy a pointer.  Make a single mistake, and the reference count is broken, silently.

Comment: @MikeBantegui - The fact of the matter is a number of large projects written in C (including, I can say with 100% certainty based on the state of the market today, the kernel you're running right now) do implement (manual) reference counting.

Comment: By "all processes using that block" do you mean "all threads using that block"?  Or perhaps "all references to that block"?

Comment: I know you need to implement your own - but here is [an example](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-memory.html) of a good reference counting mechanism in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An early problem with reference counting is that it is relatively easy to count the initial reference by putting code in a custom malloc / free implementation, but it is quite a bit harder to determine if the initial recipient passes that address around to others.

Since C lacks the ability to override the assignment operator (to count the new reference), basically you are left with a limited number of options.  The only one that can possibly override the assignment is macrodef, as it has the ability to rewrite the assignment into something that inlines the increment of the reference count value.

So you need to "expand" a macro that looks like

```
a = b;
```

into

```
if (b is a pointer) { // this might be optional, if lookupReference does this work
  struct ref_record* ref_r = lookupReference(b);
  if (ref_r) {
    ref_r->count++;
  } else {
    // error
  } 
}
a = b;
```

The real trick will be in writing a macro that can identify the assignment, and insert the code cleanly without introducing other unwanted side-effects.  Since macrodef is not a complete language, you might run into issues where the matching becomes impossible.

(jokes about seeing nails where you learn how to use a hammer have an interesting parallel here, except that when you only have a hammer, you had better learn how to make everything a nail).

Other options (perhaps more sane, perhaps not) is to keep track of all address values assigned by malloc, and then scan the program's stack and heap for matching addresses.  If you match, you *might* have found a valid pointer, or you might have found a string with a luck encoding; however, if you don't match, you certainly can free the address; provided they aren't storing an address + offset calculated from the original address. (perhaps you can macrodef to detect such offsets, and add the offset as multiple addresses in the scan for the same block)

In the end, there isn't going to be a foolproof solution without building a referencing system, where you pass back references (pretend addresses); hiding the real addresses.  The down side to such a solution is that you must use the library interface *every time* you want to deal with an address.  This includes the "next" element in the array, etc.  Not very C-like, but a pretty good approximation of what Java does with its references.

Comment: well you say 2 contrary things, one is that there's no way to override assignment the second that it can be done by macrodef... so?

Comment: They are not completely contrary statements.  Overriding is a technical term meaning "reimplement standard functionality with a non-standard implementation", while macrodef is a text expansion subsystem which won't re-implement an assignment, but you can cut and paste code if you see a "match".  It would then be up to you to see if you could first write a high-quality match and then "cut-and-paste" in the "increment the reference count" code.  It is possible in theory, but macrodef is so limited a language that it might actually be impossible due to macrodef limitations.

Comment: Looking up reference counts in a hash table is not how anybody does it.  The right way is to include the count in the structure/buffer itself.

Comment: There are no right ways, just ways that address needs.  If you want "transparent automatic" garbage collection, exposing the reference count in the struct fails the transparent part, and forces writers to increment the field after reference capture and release.  Can such a system be effective? Yes, it can!  However, it can also fail, unless care is taken to decrement the count prior to exiting local block references, etc.  Transparent automatic collection requires other techniques, which are hard to implement in pure C.

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full, eh?  I guess that "else" indentation has caught several other pairs of eyes, too...

Comment: @JamesM.Lay Don't know why the suggested edits never got enough votes; but, I fixed the else indentation for you.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Hahah thanks, it definitely satisfies my OCD now ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Semi-serious answer

```
#include "Python.h"
```

Python has a great reference counting memory manager. If I had to do this for real in production code, not homework, I'd consider embedding the python object system in my C program which would then make my C program scriptable in python too.  See [the Python C API documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/) if you are interested!

Comment: This answer refers to the Python C API, which is an interesting resource in regards to this question since said API includes reference counted C "objects".

Answer (score 2):

Such a system in C requires some discipline on the part of the programmer but ...

You need to think in terms of ownership. All things that hold references are owners and must keep track of the objects to which it holds references, e.g. through lists. When a reference holding thing is destroyed it must loop its list of referred objects and decrement their reference counters and if zero destroy them in turn.

Functions are also owners and should keep track of referenced objects, e.g. by setting up a list at the start of the function and looping through it when returning.

So you need to determine in which situations objects should be transferred or shared with new owners and wrap the corresponding situations in macros/functions that add or remove owned objects to owning objects' lists of referenced objects (and adjust the reference counter accordingly).

Finally you need to deal with circular references somehow by checking for objects that are no longer reachable from objects/pointers on the stack. That could be done with some mark and sweep garbage collection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it automatically without overridable destructors/constructors.
You can look at HDF5 ref counting but those require explicit calls in C:

http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5I.html

Comment: But why exactly do you recommend looking at HDF5?